# Auto Update A WordPress Plugin from within another WordPress Manager Plugin

Tags: updates

So I have a made a small manager plugin myself to modify some core elements from WordPress and I also hide it from my clients so they can't disable it as it also hides WPManage which is the management tool I use to control most of the websites I manage.

I've looked through the WordPress Codex and found the following: https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates

Which then provided me with the following code:

```
function auto_update_specific_plugins ($update, $item){
    $plugins = array('worker');
    if (in_array($item->slug, $plugins)){return true;}else{return $update;}
}
add_filter('auto_update_plugin','auto_update_specific_plugins',10,2);
```

I added this however into my own manager plugin lets call it SHS Manager, which is also hidden, but of course WP Manager does gets updates but as I've hidden it from within the SHS Manager plugin (which is also hidden so it can't be disabled easily) I therefore can't easily update it and am therefor looking for a way to automatically update WP Manager Worker plugin when there's an update available.

While I thought the above code worked which I did put in my SHS Manager tool, it for some reason never actually updated to WP Manager Worker Plugin at all, what am I missing here?

I made sure that the slug is the correct one being that the plugin is called 'worker' and that obviously the plugin was out of date to see if it would auto update, couple refreshes later and a period of time but it was still on the old version.

Am I missing something, are some crons required or are set in place that it only does this check once an hour or something or what am I exactly missing here that would cause this piece of code that is put in the WordPress Codex to not function correctly?

I've already searched through a lot of stack overflow similar questions but most were outdated or provided the same code that could be found on the WordPress Codex.

So any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the callback is never called? You can try `error_log( 'auto_update_specific_plugins() called' );` in the callback and check the PHP error logs. You can also inspect the `$item`, to check if `worker` is actually being passed to the callback.

Comment: It does seem to be called: [16-May-2019 14:39:54 UTC] auto_update_specific_plugins() called

Inspect the $item and slug and it indeed is all in order as far as I can see. So I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Try `var_dump( get_site_transient( 'update_plugins' ) );` and see if your plugin (`worker`) is somewhere in the data (either the `response` or `no_update` item). If so, in which item is it (`response` / `no_update`) and do you see a valid `package` (URL to the plugin's ZIP file) for your plugin?

Comment: Did a the var_dump on a fresh install with an older version of the worker plugin to make sure that it will have an "update now" label and this was the output: https://pastebin.com/yYykciin

So it has a response, it as a proper package, it shows which is the latest version, so I am really not sure to why this isn't working.

Comment: So I installed version 4.1.0 of the [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/worker/advanced/) and waited for 3 hours (but you may have to wait longer), and the plugin was *automatically* updated to version 4.8.0. And the auto-update does rely on cron - WordPress performs auto-update twice daily via [`wp_maybe_auto_update()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_maybe_auto_update/) which is triggered through [`wp_version_check()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_version_check/), but only if doing cron jobs. So how did you trigger the auto-update?